# How to shade different contours with different colors?

Tags: plotting, filling

I want these two contours to be plotted in a single figure and filled the inner regions of each contour with different colors. The problem that I am facing is the larger contour shading overshadows the smaller one. I want the inner region to be red (for x1) and the rest of the inner region for the larger contour (for x2) to be blue.  How do I achieve that?

```
x1 = ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2 + a*b}, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, Contours -> {4},
                    ContourShading -> {Red, None}, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
                   Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
                   ContourStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}];
                 
x2 = ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2}, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, Contours -> {9},
                     ContourShading -> {Blue, None}, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
                    Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
                    ContourStyle -> {Blue}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
                  
x4 = Show[{x1, x2}]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `RegionPlot[]`? `RegionPlot[{a^2 + b^2 <= 9, a^2 + b^2 + a b <= 4}, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue, Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[{0, 0}]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]`

Comment: Reverse the order in the `Show`: `x4 = Show[{x2, x1}]`

Comment: @J.M. It is working. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: @BobHanlon, It is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: @J.M., One more question. According to your suggestion, both regions are enclosed by blue boundaries. Could you please tell me how to put two different color boundaries in the two different regions? Say, for the inner one black and for the outer one green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

```
{pts1, pts2} = 
  Cases[ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2 + a*b == 4, a^2 + b^2 == 9}, {a, -7, 
      7}, {b, -7, 7}] // Normal, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
Graphics[{{Red, Polygon[pts1]}, {Blue, Polygon[pts2 -> pts1]}, {Green,
    AbsoluteThickness[2], Line@pts1}, {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line@pts2}, {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{0, 0}]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Original**

Another way is use `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` to draw the gap between the two contours to blue.

```
x1 = ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2 + a*b}, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, 
   Contours -> {4}, ContourShading -> {Red, None}, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
   Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.015], Point[{0, 0}]}, 
   ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green], Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}];
plot1 = ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2 + a*b == 4}, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Green];
plot2 = ContourPlot[a^2 + b^2 == 9, {a, -7, 7}, {b, -7, 7}, 
   ContourStyle -> Black];
plot12 = 
 Graphics[{Blue, 
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    ContourPlot[{a^2 + b^2 + a*b == 4, a^2 + b^2 == 9}, {a, -7, 
      7}, {b, -7, 7}]]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[x1, plot12, plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.